# Javascript getTime() delivers confusing results

Tags: javascript, date, utc, epoch, gettime

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find an explanation for this, in my opinion confusing behavior of `getTime()`. The documentation states:

> getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a
> client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client
> browser in any other timezone.

According to this statement, my understanding is, that e.g.

```
1. new Date (Date.UTC(2021,8,1)).getTime() // UTC           Date 1.Sep.2021 00:00:00
2. new Date (2021,8,1).getTime()           // Local (UTC+1) Date 1.Sep.2021 00:00:00
```

should deliver the same amount of milliseconds. But the results I'm getting are these:

```
1. 1630454400000
2. 1630447200000 // 1 hour (3600000 ms) missing
```

**Question A**: Physically the same amount of time has passed since 1.1.1970. Why are the results not equal (also daylight saving matters!) like they should, according to the docs?

**Question B**: If the behavior is correct, why is there one hour missing? Shouldn't there be one hour more? Logically UTC+1 is one hour ahead.

Comment: `new Date (Date.UTC(2021,8,1))` -> UTC, `new Date (2021,8,1)` -> local - all mentioned in the [documentation over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: Ist logical because your second date is utc+1 so the utc seconds till 1970 are 1 hour minus the date

Comment: `new Date(value)` -> `value`: _"An integer value representing the number of **milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC** (the ECMAScript epoch, equivalent to the UNIX epoch), with leap seconds ignored."_ / `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)`: _"Individual date and time component values ... **The parameter values are all evaluated against the local time zone, rather than UTC**"_

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for your reply. I've read the MDN docs (multiple times ;-)). But as mentioned there it says the results of getTime() should be equal (independent of the timezone).

Comment: The return value of `.getTime()` will always be "UTC" (the difference in seconds since ...) . But the dates you pass to the `Date` constructor are treated differently because one is in UTC and one in your lcoal time.

Comment: That's fully understood. But I'm still wondering why the doc says that getTime() results should be equal independent of the timezone.

Comment: _"That's fully understood"_ - Obviously not ;) The return value will always be milliseconds since X in UTC relative to the timestamp stored in that `Date` instance. This doesn't change the fact, that the time stored in your `Date` instances are two different timestamps. One constructed from a UTC timestamp (the first), and one from a local timestamp (the second). `.getTime()` cannot return the same result for different timestamps (UTC != local time).

Comment: The short answer is that the code you have in your question will always produce `1630454400000` as the first result regardless of the timezone in which you run it.

Comment: @ChrisG, yes I agree for the first one, but the second result has obviously one hour less because I'm in UTC+1. I've just switched my machine to UTC+2 and then it gives me 1630443600000 (so another hour less). Thus the second code line does not deliver the same result in every timezone

Comment: I'm guessing the confusion is caused primarily by the fact that the sentence from the doc is kind of superfluous; it's not much deeper than stating that `10 - 7` will evaluate to `3` in every browser. `.getTime()` essentially provides the result of a subtraction, it gives the milliseconds that have passed between date A and date B. date A is midnight on Jan 1st, 1970 UTC. So provided that date B is the same across timezones, the difference is also the same across timezones, and therefore the result of getTime() is the same across timezones.

Comment: `new Date (2021,8,1)` however will produce different points in time based on which timezone the script runs in (because it uses local time), therefore the difference to a fixed UTC point in time will also vary across browsers. Running `new Date (2021,8,1)` in GMT+0 and GMT+1 gives two Dates one hour apart, and therefore getTime() will give two numbers 3600000 milliseconds apart. This does not contradict the sentence from the docs however, because the input date was not the same for both timezones.

Comment: To put it short, `getTime()` is indeed independent of timezone (and a `Date` instance doesn't contain any timezone information by itself). What is NOT independent of timezone is the way you instantiate your `Date` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what caused the confusion. Thanks for all your help! Especially to Chris G who pointed me in the right direction. Here is what screwed up my brain ;-)

All who didn't understand why there is an issue at all, were most likely looking at this from a regular webrowser user's point of view. In that scenario if a user in UTC+1 opens a website which calls `getTime()` at lets say 1. Sept. 2021 07:00:00, that would result in this:

```
now Date ( 2021, 8, 1, 7, 0, 0 ).getTime()
```

Now if a second user does the same at exactly the same moment in UTC+0, this would result in:

```
now Date ( 2021, 8, 1, 6, 0, 0 ).getTime()
```

Then of course we are getting the same results! My problem was that I assumed that calling:

```
now Date ( 2021, 8, 1, 7, 0, 0 ).getTime()
```

in different time zones should give the same result. Which is NOT the case! Now you may ask why someone would need this. The reason is simple. I'm developing a little Gantt tool in Electron and there I need to compare/subtract dates. Of course I don't need the above to be true (deliver the same values), but I came accross this problem, because I was not getting divisable numbers of milliseconds when subtracting dates by converting them to ms with `getTime()`. I was expecting that according to the doc, which says that `getTime()` will give the same value in every time zone, to get an absolute value which is not influenced by time zones or daylight saving, for calculation. Thus I expected that e.g.:

```
now Date(2021,4,1,0,0,0).getTime() - now Date(2021,11,1,0,0,0).getTime()
```

Should give a number of milliseconds, which should be perfectly divisiable by 86400000 (one day). But that was not the case. The reason is that the second date is 1h behind because of daylight saving!

**Conclusion**

The statement in the doc is true when looking at the same point in time (e.g. UTC+0
06:00 and UTC+1 07:00), but not when looking at the same number of hours (e.g. UTC+0
07:00 and UTC+1 07:00). That was what confused me. Maybe this explanation helps others as well.